# Titanium JS: cannot use an image stored in SQLite Database in TiSocial module

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

My app has a bunch of images stored as blobs in the local SQLite Database. These images are taken with the device camera. I'm using Titanium Alloy, so the image was saved using the `.save()` method an Alloy Model.

I've started using the [TiSocial module](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework) that can post an image to Twitter or Facebook. One its parameters is `image` and it has to be:

> a local/remote path to an image you want to share

The image I want to use is set as the image property on an ImageView. The ImageView image is set like this: `$.theImageView.image = args.the_image;`, where `args.image` is the image blob, taken from the database collection.

I tried to take this image blob and set it as the image on the [TiSocial module](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework) initialisation method:

```
Social.activityView({
    text: "Hello world! Take a look at this: " + args.name,
    image: args.the_image,
    removeIcons:"airdrop,print,copy,contact,camera"
});
```

Alternatively I tried to take use the image saved on the ImageView, like this:

```
Social.activityView({
    text: "Hello world! Take a look at this: " + args.name,
    image: $.theImageView.image,
    removeIcons:"airdrop,print,copy,contact,camera"
});
```

However neither of these worked, and no image appears in the Tweet or Facebook message dialogs. And no error appears in the console.

On the other hand, if I set the `image` property to an image saved in the `assets` folder, then it works just fine. For example:

```
`image: "an_image.jpg"`
```

I tried a solution mentioned in the comments below, which was to save the image to Ti.FileSystem, and then read the image from there. However, this still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some luck by saving the file to the Ti.Filesystem, and then later retrieving it and using the `.getNativePath()` method:

```
function getImage() {
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, args.alloy_id + '.jpg');  
    return f.read();  
 }

var theImage = getImage();

Social.activityView({
    text: "Just tried this beer called " + args.name,
    image: theImage.getNativePath(),
    removeIcons:"airdrop,print,copy,contact,camera"
});
```

Comment: this is the way i am trying to convince you in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try sharing remote images this way...

```
var largeImg = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height : 'auto',
        image :'http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/splashes/featured.png'
    });

var imageGoogle =largeImg.toBlob();

// share image
Social.activityView({
    status : "Hello world! Take a look at this: ",
    image : imageGoogle,
    removeIcons:"airdrop,print,copy,contact,camera"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

then i would suggest to add one field called img_path in your database table because you can not get path from blob so when you store any blob to alloy model then also add its path to that model so you can retrieve it later and can share.

Hope you understand.

Comment: How do you add a path for an image when you store any blob to a model? Please bare in mind that these images are being taken with the devices camera.

Comment: oh..then you should describe this in your questions so that we can know that you are actually store blob image taken by camera.

so I would suggest to store images in applicationDataDirectory and store only image name in model so that you can get it back.

Comment: Ok thank you Mitul Bhalia, I've updated my question. Can edit your question and give an example of your idea?

Comment: I just wanted to say that first save blob in applicationDataDirectory with Ti.Filesystem object.

Ex. say image name is test.png then use that name to store image in dataDirectory then use that image name to store image in model...

so later you can get that image with test.png from model and read it with Ti.Filesystem.